# ListView.getChildAt(correctPos) does not work from Android 2.3.x and down

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm working on a navigation drawer which is supposed to use diffrent backgrounds for each item in the list. Therefore I'm using the following code (onClick):

```
private class NavBarClickHandler implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}

private void selectItem(int position) {
    if(oldPos != position)
    {
        oldPos = position;
        cont.removeAllViews();
        for(int i = 0; i < leftBar.getChildCount(); i++)
            leftBar.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#111111"));
        setTitle(leftBarEntries[position]);
        leftBar.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colorArray[position%colorArray.length]));
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(colorArray[position%colorArray.length])));

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            cont.addView(LI.inflate(R.layout.hem, cont, false));
            break;

        case 1:
            cont.addView(LI.inflate(R.layout.hem, cont, false));
            break;

        case 2:
            cont.addView(LI.inflate(R.layout.kalender, cont, false));
            break;

        case 3:
            cont.addView(LI.inflate(R.layout.kalender, cont, false));
            break;

        }
    }
    whole.closeDrawer(leftBar);
}
```

This works fine... On android 3.0 and up. When the code is run on an emulator based on Android 2.x however, the part

`leftBar.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colorArray[position%colorArray.length]));`

sets the correct backgroundcolor, but to the wrong item.

My tests suggests that on the first click, getChild is calculated from the bottom (Meaning top item is item 3 and bottom item is item 0), second click is calculated from top, third from bottom etc.
However this is the only line reacting in this way (`position` is always equal to 0 when top item is selected)
This line (nothing else??) is also executed every time you press the same item more than once, changing which item that shows the background after the above pattern. This is supposed to be prevented by `if(oldPs != position)`

[image: (Problem description in image)]

Therefore:

1.Why is this happening?

2.How can I make this work for android 2.x?

Comment: `leftBar` is a ListView?

Comment: Yes, it is a ListView.

Answer (score 0):

A `ListView` adds and remove its children for efficiency reasons. When scrolling, invisible views in the list are removed and newly visible views created (or recycled from the invisible ones). The child order may not reflect the list order.

To do what you want, create your own `ListAdapter`, e.g. by extending the `ArrayAdapter` class and overriding `getView()`. This method gets a parameter `position` which is the position you want. You can call the super-method to retrieve a view, modify the background and return it.